# How to call a div's onclick handler when pressing Enter?

Tags: javascript, html, enter

All of this code here works perfectly fine, I just want to make it more easy for the user by allowing him/her to just hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the function, instead of having to click the `div` activating the `moneyFunction()`.

Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> YearlyDough </title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="money.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p id="header"> Enter yearly income </p>
    <input type="text" id="textmoney">
    <div onclick="moneyFunction()" id="moneydiv"> <p id="divtext">Calculate</p> </div>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="liar"></p>

    <div onclick="reloadFunction()" id="reload"> Redo </div>

    <a href="aboutmoney.html" id="about"> About </a>


    <script>
    function moneyFunction() {
        var money = document.getElementById('textmoney').value;
        var dailyE = money/365;

        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ("$" + dailyE + " " + "per day");

    if ( document.getElementById('textmoney').value == 0) {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "ERROR";
    }
    if ( document.getElementById('textmoney').value > 100000000000) {
            document.getElementById('liar').innerHTML = "I know you aint make that much.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('liar').innerHTML = "";
    }
    }   

    function reloadFunction() {
        location.reload();
    } 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var inp = document.getElementById("textmoney");
inp.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //checks whether the pressed key is "Enter"
        moneyFunction();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.div').click()
```

Inside your keydown event will call the onclick if you have jquery included on the page.